# Relative path to image folder java spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, path

I have a problem with a relative path to an image folder.
I want to list the images into a folder to add their urls to a list and show them in a jsp.
The code is this:

```
File carpetaImagenes = new File("../../../../../webapp/resources/img/maquinas/"+seleccion);
    List<String> listaUrlImagenes = new ArrayList<String>();  

    /** Recorremos el directorio de imagenes de la maquina */
    for(File imagen : carpetaImagenes.listFiles()){  
      String imageFileName = imagen.getName();          
      listaUrlImagenes.add(imageFileName);  
    }
```

The result of "carpetaImagenes.listFiles()" is always null. I suppose the path is bad.
Here you can see the image of the folder tree. The class is into "controlador" folder and the images are into "webbapp/resources/img/maquinas/1"
[image]

I haeve tried several paths with no luck.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

User following method getImageList and it should work

```
relativeFilePath = "img/maquinas/"+seleccion;
```

This is a relative path from classpath. I assume ../../../../../webapp/resources is your actual folder where everyrthing is deployed .

```
private List getImageList(String relativeFilePath) {
List<String> listaUrlImagenes = new ArrayList<String>();
try {

    InputStream in = getResourceAsStream(relativeFilePath);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    String resource;

    while ((resource = br.readLine()) != null) {
        listaUrlImagenes.add(resource);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return listaUrlImagenes;
}
private InputStream getResourceAsStream(String resource) {
final InputStream in = ClassLoader cl = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(
        resource);

return in == null ? getClass().getResourceAsStream(resource) : in;
}
```

And in **spring** following should work.

```
ClassLoader cl = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
ResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver(
        cl);
Resource[] resources = resolver.getResources("classpath:/img/maquinas/"+seleccion);// or *.png
for (Resource resource : resources) {

 listaUrlImagenes.add(resource.getFilename());
}
```

Comment: I have tried the spring way and it does not work. Images are into src/webapp/resources/img/maquinas/1

Comment: what about the other option ?

Comment: Doesn't work. Null pointer at the method call. I think the relative path is wrong

Comment: did you try taking out that backslash? "classpath:img/maquinas/"

Answer (score 0):

Finally working!!

```
File carpetaImagenes = new ClassPathResource("imagenes/maquinas/"+seleccion).getFile();
    File[] listaImagenes = carpetaImagenes.listFiles();
```